Consider a scroll area for lengthy Markdown tables
The wonderful galacticninja converted a <pre> formatted tabbed dataset to a Markdown table on my answer here: How many Pokemon can be obtained only in Emerald?
As much as I appreciated it, the problem is this table is 386 rows long - by design, containing a list of every available Pokemon in Pokemon Emerald. This blows the length of the answer completely out of proportion. Users would have to scroll too far to get beyond the data table present. So unfortunately, I had to roll it back.
The original <pre> formatted area only takes up ~600px of screen space, by using a scroll area to 'hide' the rest of the data. However, no such height limitation exists for Markdown tables.
I'm wondering if a similar scroll area can be applied to Markdown tables beyond a certain amount of rows?
What needs to change
It should hopefully be a relatively minor fix. Currently, the CSS for the markdown table container is as follows:
.s-table-container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    scrollbar-color: var(--scrollbar) transparent;
}

Changing overflow-x to just overflow, and adding a max-height, adds a scrollbar to the y-axis and restricts it's height to a max of 600px:
.s-table-container {
    overflow: auto;
    scrollbar-color: var(--scrollbar) transparent;
    max-height: 600px;
}

You could also potentially make the table header sticky, but honestly, the above would be enough.
See this sandbox answer which has both the <pre> formatted area, and the Markdown table for comparison.

The problem with a standard max height is that it might occlude very small portions of tables which just exceed 600 or x px. "Beyond a certain amount of rows" would be awesome, but I'm not sure that's easy to implement.

@Joachim gotta set the cutoff somewhere. Plus, using max height means it would only scroll if you exceed that size, same as the preformatted area. Also, when I said calculated based on the number of rows, it would still be based on the height of rows. E.g. 10 rows at 50px height would be 500px, etc.
